# Peugeot 407 2004 with unusual sound when clutching

Tags: noise, clutch, manual-transmission, peugeot

When I drive there is an unusual sound when I'm pressing and releasing the clutch. It sounds like something that is spinning and grinding. There is a little sound there if clutching when not driving as well, but not the louder spinning sound. I would guess this is something with the transmission? Maybe getting a clutch kit? Any ideas or suggestions would be great.

Listen: https://on.soundcloud.com/e6xx9

Here's what I do:

- Accelerating
- 0:04 press clutch
- Gearing
- 0:07 releasing clutch
- Accelerating
- 0:10 press clutch

Comment: Not knowing what actions are happening when the sound occurs, I'm not even sure what I'm listening for or when. Can you take a video showing what you're doing with your foot which might correlate to the sound better?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Good point! I have updated a short list in the OP of what I do.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely thing is that the clutch release bearing is worn.  This bearing is a thrust bearing and it is only used while the clutch pedal is pressed.  It is a good idea not to leave it making this noise for too long, even though the clutch is working, since it can add wear to the pressure plate fingers that it presses against and could also eventually totally fail.

You can see the clutch release bearing in yellow on this [drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clutch#/media/File:Car_clutch.png)

Comment: Yeah, after some research I have also thought about the clutch release bearing. I've also started to consider if there might have been a leakage of transmission fluid. I don't have equipment to get under the car at the moment, so I guess I will have to contact the workshop anyway.